# Compare the file timestamp with current time in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I have a windows script for reading file that is put by an application within a time limit. The script times out in 1 min.
If the application was late in putting the file then there will be an old file lying in the folder.
Next time the script is executed it will read the old file instead of the new one.

I want to compare the timestamp of the file with the timestamp the script was executed.
How can I get the timestamp when the file was placed on the folder in .bat file?

Thanks

Comment: If you really have a script, don't hesitate to show it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it is for the default European time format:

```
for %%a in (file) do set "filestamp=%%~ta"
set "datestamp=%date%  %time:~0,5%"
if "%datestamp%"=="%filestamp%" (
    rem read this
) else (
    rem read this NOT
)
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro! The filestamp prints 07/29/2013 02:52 PM but the datestamp prints Tue 07/30/2013  14:28. These will never be equal.

Comment: that's true! You should synchonize your time format: both European or both AM/PM.

Comment: Endoro - How to check whether the datestamp is less than the filestamp?